# JSON or CSV need suggestion

Tags: java, android, json, csv

I need some suggestions for the App am developing,

I have some 6 sensors which are continuously sending the data to the App, I need to log the data in some file. I want to know which is the better approach to store such data. I tired using json by storing all the values in one json objects, and created a array of json objects somewhat like this

```
[{sensor1, senor2, sensor3, sensor4, sensor5, sensor6},{sensor1, senor2, sensor3, sensor4, sensor5, sensor6}]
```

But I have more then 20000 data like this to store, creating the array of 20000 json object and writing to file in one shot looks expensive. on that data is coming once in 15 seconds. writing one JSON object once in every 15 second will disturb the JSON format.

So I need suggestion like is using JSON method to store this data is better or I should think of some other method like CSV??

Comment: where are you going to store the data, file or database?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the data points over time, have you considered using a time series database? There are various NoSQL style databases that are well suited to this task, Cassandra being one

https://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt, CSV.

But only if you're certain your format will not change (always 6 sensors). Furthermore, in CSV, data can be added at the end of a file while in JSON you have to write in the middle.

Comment: Thank you @will421 for the suggestion, I have to update the file regularly whenever the data is available from the sensor which I will append to the end of the file every time. I don't think I can do this efficiently with the JSON so am going for CSV